# React router with typescript how to import intrinsic attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

First time using Typescript, I'm rendering a component inside of a map like this:

```
interface chatInterface {
  sender: string;
  avatar: string;
  content: string;
  time: string;
}
<>    
  {eachUser?.chats.map((item) =>
                  item.messages.map((obj: chatInterface, index: number) => {
                    return <ChatPage key={index} message={obj} />;
                  })
                )}
</>
```

And the ChatPage component is this:

```
function ChatPage(props: { message: chatInterface }) {
  const { sender, avatar, content, time } = props.message;
  return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <strong>{sender}:</strong> {content} at:{time}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And it's working fine, but i want to create a page for the ChatPage component, but i don't know how i should import it in the react router. This is my app.tsx component:

```
<Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/chat" element={<ChatPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

It says that:

```
Property 'message' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ message: chatInterface; }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `ChatPage` component is missing a better type declaration. The error is saying that the `message` prop is required and missing. In other words, it isn't an optional prop.

Make `message` an optional property and handle the destructuring fallback value in the component.

Example:

```
interface chatPageInterface {
  message?: chatInterface;
}

function ChatPage(props: chatPageInterface) {
  const { sender, avatar, content, time } = props.message || {};
  return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <strong>{sender}:</strong> {content} at:{time}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you help me one more time? How should i pass a function as props? I tried passing it to the component like `removeFriend={( )=>removeFriend(index)}` and to the interface as `removeFriend= ( ) => { }`. But at the route component it says `Property 'removeFriend' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'chatPageInterface'`

Comment: @JoséCarlos I think you should probably be passing some of these props to this `ChatPage` component where you are rendering it on a route. Currently it doesn't appear any props are passed at all. Do you have a codesandbox demo of your code we could take a look at?